# VBA to change Visio font style by font name instead of font index?

Tags: vba, visio

I'm hoping to use VBA to change the font style of the texts in shapes(from Calibri to Verdana). Currently I have (a snippet of the code)

```
Visio.ActivePage.Shapes(1).Characters.CharProps(visCharacterFont) = 235#
```

235 is the font index for Verdana in my system. However, the font index is very unstable and can change on different computers. Is there a way to change the font style by font name instead, e.g. ...="Verdana"? It's possible in excel, but I couldn't find similar syntax in Visio. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can check what is **ID** for Verdana font on current PC

```
Dim Verdana_ID As Integer
Verdana_ID = ActiveDocument.Fonts.Item("Verdana").ID
```

And after this step set this **ID** as character's font

```
Visio.ActivePage.Shapes(1).Characters.CharProps(visCharacterFont) = Verdana_ID
```